# How to push the key and value to an array in angular controller

Tags: angularjs, arrays

I want to filter data on the basis of number of rows and columns provided by user.

I am getting the data on controller after reading the excel file from given location and the excel may contain multiple sheets. The sheet names would come in dropdown.

I want to filter the row data on the basis of the header names which are coming through column so that the row has only the values till the column is defined. Currently I am getting entire row values.

I have written a logic like this but this is not working.

```
var rowData=[];
for(var i=0;i<headerNames.length;i++){//headerNames contains column names
   for(var j=0;j<data.length;j++){//data contains the rows data
      for(var keyName in data[j])
        if(angular.equals(keyName,headerNames[i])){
           rowData.push({'keyName':data[j][keyName]})//I want only the key,values which matches the column names. I want to set the keyName value as array key but I am not getting its value instead it is coming like keyName:18
        }
      }
   }
}
```

Adding the plunker for the code.
http://plnkr.co/edit/28Z44xDBug7nFCQnKZJL?p=preview

I am able to filter the data on UI and get only the row and column data as per user input.
But i need the same data on controller, so that i can save it in MongoDb. I want to filter the row data as per the column input. So, that i only get the row data till the column is defined.

Please suggest how can i filter the data and can splice the row values so that in row i can have value upto the column numbers defined. For eg, if  user have entered 4 rows and 5 columns then in my row Data i can have only values upto 5th column and all other values i can remove from array. in my code currently i am not able to get the key value to be set as array key.

Please help me to resolve this issue.

Answer (score -1):

You should try to change to this in your inner loop:

```
var obj = {};
obj[keyName] = data[j][keyName];
rowData.push(obj);
```

Note: I also made some improvements on the sheet selection, now it defaults to the first sheet when you upload a new file.
I also think you have an issue with your reset, it does not accept a new workbook after a reset, it just uses the previous one.

```js
// Code goes here
angular.module('app', ['ui.grid'])
    .controller('MainCtrl', ['$scope', function ($scope) {
        var vm = this;
        vm.gridOptions = {};
        vm.reset = reset;
        vm.selectedSheet = '';
        vm.sheetIndex = 0;
        function reset() {
            vm.gridOptions.data = [];
            vm.gridOptions.columnDefs = [];
            vm.selectedSheet = '';
            vm.sheetIndex = 0;
            vm.sheetNames = [];
            vm.updatedData = null;
        }

        vm.readSheet = function () {
            var workbook = XLSX.read(vm.data, {
                type: 'binary'
            });
            var headerNames = XLSX.utils.sheet_to_json(workbook.Sheets[workbook.SheetNames[vm.sheetIndex]], {
                header: 1
            })[0];
            vm.sheetNames = workbook.SheetNames; //Passed the sheet names to scope variable
            if(!vm.selectedSheet && vm.sheetNames && vm.sheetNames.length > 0) {
                vm.selectedSheet = vm.sheetNames[0];
            }
            var data = XLSX.utils.sheet_to_json(workbook.Sheets[workbook.SheetNames[vm.sheetIndex]]);
            var row = $scope.rowCount;
            var col = $scope.columnCount;
            if (col != undefined && col != '') {
                headerNames.splice($scope.columnCount);
            }
            vm.gridOptions.columnDefs = [];
            headerNames.forEach(function (h) {
                vm.gridOptions.columnDefs.push({
                    field: h
                });
            });
            if (row != undefined && row != '') {
                data.splice($scope.rowCount);
            }
            vm.gridOptions.data = data;
            var rowData = [];
            for (var i = 0; i < headerNames.length; i++) {
                for (var j = 0; j < data.length; j++) {
                    for (var keyName in data[j]) {
                        if (angular.equals(keyName, headerNames[i])) {
                            var obj = {};
                            obj[keyName] = data[j][keyName];
                            rowData.push(obj);//Here I am trying to create 
                            //an similar data kind array which will have only the row values upto
                            //the column defined. But in keyName I am not getting the key value
                            //Also please suggest is this the right approach. I need only the data
                            //here upto the row and column defined by user so that I can save that data
                            //to mongoDB
                        }
                    }
                }
            }
            vm.updatedData = rowData;
        };
        vm.onLoadData = function (data) {
            vm.data = vm.data || data;
            vm.readSheet();
        };
        vm.sheetChange = function () {
            vm.sheetIndex = vm.sheetNames.indexOf(vm.selectedSheet);
            vm.readSheet();
        };
        $scope.$watch('columnCount', function(newVal, oldVal) {
            if(newVal !== oldVal) {
                vm.readSheet();
            }
        });
        $scope.$watch('rowCount', function(newVal, oldVal) {
            if(newVal !== oldVal) {
                vm.readSheet();
            }
        });
    }])
    .directive("fileread", [function () {
        return {
            scope: {
                onLoadData: '&'
            },
            link: function ($scope, $elm, $attrs) {
                $elm.on('change', function (changeEvent) {
                    var reader = new FileReader();
                    reader.onload = function (evt) {
                        $scope.$apply(function () {
                            $scope.onLoadData({
                                data: evt.target.result
                            });
                            $elm.val(null);
                        });
                    };
                    reader.readAsBinaryString(changeEvent.target.files[0]);
                });
            }
        }
    }]);
```

```css
/* Styles go here */

body {
  /* font-family: Verdana; */
  padding: 20px;
}

.grid {
  width: 100%;
  height: 250px;
}

.grid-msg-overlay {
  position: absolute;
  top: 0;
  bottom: 0;
  width: 100%;
  background: rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.4);
}

.grid-msg-overlay .msg {
  opacity: 1;
  position: absolute;
  top: 20%;
  left: 20%;
  width: 60%;
  height: 50%;
  background-color: #eee;
  border-radius: 4px;
  border: 1px solid #555;
  text-align: center;
  font-size: 24px;
  display: table;
}

.grid-msg-overlay .msg > .center {
  display: table-cell;
  vertical-align: middle;
}

.grid input[type="file"] {
  font-size: 14px;
  display: inline-block;
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html ng-app="app">

  <head>
    <link data-require="bootstrap-css@*" data-semver="3.3.1" rel="stylesheet" href="//maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.1/css/bootstrap.min.css" />
    <script src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.3.16/angular.js"></script>
    <script src="https://cdn.rawgit.com/SheetJS/js-xlsx/v0.8.0/dist/xlsx.full.min.js"></script>
    <script src="https://cdn.rawgit.com/SheetJS/js-xlsx/v0.8.0/dist/ods.js"></script>
    <script src="http://cdn.rawgit.com/angular-ui/ui-grid.info/gh-pages/release/3.0.0-rc.22/ui-grid.min.js"></script>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="http://cdn.rawgit.com/angular-ui/ui-grid.info/gh-pages/release/3.0.0-rc.22/ui-grid.min.css" />
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="main.css" type="text/css" />
  </head>

  <body>
   <div ng-controller="MainCtrl as vm">
      <button type="button" class="btn btn-success" ng-click="vm.reset()">Reset Grid</button>
      <br />
      <br />
      <div id="grid1" ui-grid="vm.gridOptions" class="grid">
        <div class="grid-msg-overlay" ng-show="!vm.gridOptions.data.length">
          <div class="msg">
            <div class="center">
              <span class="muted">Select Spreadsheet File</span>
              <br />
               <input type="file" accept=".xls,.xlsx,.ods"  multiple="true"  fileread="" on-load-data="vm.onLoadData(data)"/>
            </div>
          </div>
        </div>
      </div>
      <div ng-show="vm.sheetNames && vm.sheetNames.length > 0">
        <br/>
        <div ng-show="vm.sheetNames.length > 1">
          <select ng-model="vm.selectedSheet" ng-options="names as names for names in vm.sheetNames" 
          ng-change="vm.sheetChange()"></select>
        </div>
        <br/>
        <label>Column:
          <input type="text" name="col" ng-model="columnCount">
        </label>
        <br/>
        <label>Row:
          <input type="text" name="row" ng-model="rowCount">
        </label>
        <br/><br/>
        <div ng-show="vm.updatedData">
          <label>Updated result:</label>
          <div>{{vm.updatedData}}</div>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
    <script src="app.js"></script>
  </body>

</html>
```

[Plunker update](http://plnkr.co/edit/M4HD0v1D8RAUvXIgOGE7)

Comment: Hi, thank you for your reply. I run your plunker but currently in that I am getting values like rowData:[0:{ageDuration:18};1:{ageDuration:19},2:{ageDuration:20}].Instead i need that in the 0th index 1st row data should come upto the column number defined. Then in the 1st index second row data should come like that. It is coming the same way in data object but i need to remove the column data from there which is not present in headernames

Comment: Ok, so I updated the snippet and the plunker. I added the print out of what the result will be. But I don't know if I get what you want, can you show me an example of an input and expected output?